# Deleting table rows using this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rows, removechild

I'm trying to build an event that would delete a row in my table.In every row I have delete button and applicable row should be deleted once button in this row is clicked. Is there a way to do it using 'this' property? I tried with calculating indexes for row and button but it was too confusing, I am looking for simpler code. Here is what I got till now, part with 'this' doesn't work obviously. Can you advise if there is similar way to select applicable row?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteBtn");

    function removeItem (e) {

        var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

        rows[this].parentNode.removeChild(rows[this]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
    }
 })
```

Comment: this is a button, has nothing to do with the rows and index... It you want to get the row, than just use parentNodes to you get to the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will refer to your `.deleteBtn` element. Assuming that's inside the row you want to remove, you need to traverse up that element's parents to find the `tr`, and then remove it:

```
function removeItem(e) {
    var tr = this;
    while (tr.tagName != "TR") {
        tr = tr.parentNode;
        if (!tr) {
            // Didn't find an ancestor TR
            return;
        }
    }
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

On modern browsers you could change the `removeChild` line to just:

```
tr.remove();
```

...but I have to admit I don't know how well-supported that is (I'm looking at you, Microsoft).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that 'this' refers to button. I tried reaching tr with this.parentElement.parentElement and that worked.

Comment: @Joanna: That will work until/unless you change your structure; it's more robust to search as above.